# Colours in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, default

I have recently started using Ubuntu and the terminal by default very helpfully had different colours for the directory I was in and other things. I don't know what I did and now the colour of everything is all white (plus all my cookies and history from the browser were deleted as well as all my files on VS code). I have tried the commands `tput init`, `reset`, and `tput sgr0` but none of them have worked.
Does anyone know how I can fix this please?
Thanks

Comment: If you don't know what you did, it might be very difficult to help you. However, check the question above, and see if any of the fixes apply to you. It's good to know how terminal colors work, and how to configure this.